# How can I know the default wmode value of an object element?

Tags: javascript, html, flash, wmode

I am debugging a webpage with some flash objects which have no wmode set. I need to know which value the browser or flash player is assigning to them.

Comment: Do they not show up in the element inspector?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The default wmode should be `window` [according to the docs](http://helpx.adobe.com/flash/kb/flash-object-embed-tag-attributes.html#main_Using_Window_Mode__wmode__values_).

Comment: Seems not to be happening in Chrome